# Show current date in html in angular component

Tags: angular

I use angular 8.
In my html I need to display current date.

Here is html code:

```
   <label class="col-md-4">Creation date </label>
   <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="date"/>
```

How can I display in html above current date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your component.ts file, you can get the date as,

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   dateVal = new Date();
```

and display in the component.html, if you want to format you can use [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) as you need

```
{{dateVal | date: 'M/dd/yyyy'}}
```

If you need to display in input, you can do

```
<input type="date" [ngModel] ="dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="dt = $event">
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example-bherkk)**

Comment: How can I put it inside input tag

Answer (score 3):

For reactive form, you can try like this:

```
myForm:FormGroup;

this.myForm = new FormGroup({    
 'date': new FormControl((new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10))
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-5q9a7u?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**